# Selenium Webdriver login to certain website fails where human succeeds

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing an application which automatically aggregates the orders we have made across multiple appliance sellers like ao.com and currys.co.uk.

On one of those sites (currys.co.uk) we've run into a problem. Logging in does not seem possible with Selenium (Chrome on mac in this case) WebDriver, but the exact same actions (as far as I can tell) by a human in the browser do work.

https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/s/authentication.html is the URL.

I've simplified this slightly to remove most of the conditional or wait logic which might be required for real use.

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Goto login page
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/s/authentication.html")
# Close cookie popup if shown
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
except:
    pass
# Enter email address
driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sEmail").send_keys("example@example.com")
# Enter password
driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sPassword").send_keys("redacted")
# Select remember-me
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-checkbox").click()
# Get submit button
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-button")))
# Submit with click
submit_button.click()
# Submit with return key
# driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sPassword").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# Submit with JS
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_button)
```

The weird thing is that any of the 3 submit methods I attempted seems to do a submit as it results in a 302 (this is also what happens when login is conducted by a human). However, the user is not logged in and the webdriver loads the same auth page again with no error or warning.

In contrast, if a human (even in the Chrome instance spawned by WebDriver) is the one to click the submit button, the user is logged in. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Related might be that in Selenium, even if I set `user-data-dir` in the options to a profile (unused for anything else), a user login is never remembered between browser session... even when a human does the login. This is in contrast to what happens when I login using my ordinary Chrome browser.

```py
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir='/tmp/profile)}')
```

The only conclusion I can draw is that something Currys are doing on their end prevents this from being possible, but I'm hoping not as otherwise the app isn't going to work for this one website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look and I can agree it's rather odd. I have theories why it's not working - but nothing I can seem to prove.

The good news is there's a work around. Log in twice.

Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Goto login page
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/s/authentication.html")
# Close cookie popup if shown
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
except:
    pass
# Enter email address
driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sEmail").send_keys("example@example.com")
# Enter password
driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sPassword").send_keys("redacted")
# Select remember-me
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-checkbox").click()
# Get submit button
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-button")))
# Submit with click
submit_button.click()


#dont need this twice - remembers friom previous run
#driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sEmail").send_keys("example@example.com")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-sPassword").send_keys("redacted")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-checkbox").click()
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dc-button")))
submit_button.click()
```

Even with your junk credentials, the first time i run the script it does as you describe. However, the second time around - it seems to actually respond. This is the state at the end of the script - looks like it would work if you have real credentials:
[image]

---

UPDATE:

It seems to be the page your landing on and potentially the way the cookies are set or something about the JS.

As another approach to test the boundaries of the issue -
If you land on the home page & Accept the cookies, then navigate to the authentication and log in it seems to work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Goto login page - use this to get the cookies
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/index.html")
# Close cookie popup if shown
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
except:
    pass

#then proceed to login
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/s/authentication.html")

### then the rest!
```

Comment: Fabulous! I'm glad that it was just weirdness in their website and not just me! This works really well. Any idea about why the login cookie (I.e. "remember me") appears to have no effect? I know that other cookies are being persisted to the user-data because the cookie for allowing cookies is remembered!